# Swift- EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) how to find the exception with this stack trace

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

swift - unable to decode the stack trace, how to find where the exception occurs

Does anyone know anything about this crash? That all the information here, I still don't know whats wrong about it. The important is that I found many crash contain this part,
this is the stack trace that I have got here,
the stack trace has no controller names or row numbers to begin with,
its like a matrix of code

> Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
>       Exception Codes: 0x00000000 at 0x0000000000000000
>       Crashed Thread: 0
>
> ```
> Application Specific Information:
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
> ```
>
> number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (51) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (50), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
>
> ```
> Thread 0 Crashed:
> 0 CoreFoundation 0x000000021ecd5ea4 0x21ebb9000 + 1167012
> 1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000021dea5a50 objc_exception_throw + 56
> 2 CoreFoundation 0x000000021ebeba2c 0x21ebb9000 + 207404
> 3 Foundation 0x000000021f6da1d0 0x21f64e000 + 573904
> 4 UIKitCore 0x000000024c068268 0x24b58c000 + 11387496
> 5 UIKitCore 0x000000024c0805b4 0x24b58c000 + 11486644
> 6 UIKitCore 0x000000024c0806c0 0x24b58c000 + 11486912
> 7 DCMobileApp 0x0000000100771d08 0x100724000 + 318728
> 8 DCMobileApp 0x00000001007a84ac 0x100724000 + 541868
> 9 DCMobileApp 0x0000000100790a54 0x100724000 + 445012
> 10 DCMobileApp 0x000000010087cdc8 0x100724000 + 1412552
> 11 DCMobileApp 0x000000010097b12c 0x100724000 + 2453804
> 12 DCMobileApp 0x00000001007d7818 0x100724000 + 735256
> 13 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000021e70d6c8 0x21e6ad000 + 394952
> 14 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000021e70e484 0x21e6ad000 + 398468
> 15 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000021e6ba9a4 0x21e6ad000 + 55716
> 16 CoreFoundation 0x000000021ec65ce4 0x21ebb9000 + 707812
> 17 CoreFoundation 0x000000021ec60bac 0x21ebb9000 + 687020
> 18 CoreFoundation 0x000000021ec600e0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
> 19 GraphicsServices 0x0000000220ed9584 GSEventRunModal + 100
> 20 UIKitCore 0x000000024be74c00 UIApplicationMain + 212
> 21 DCMobileApp 0x0000000100731a50 0x100724000 + 55888
> 22 libdyld.dylib 0x000000021e71ebb4 0x21e71e000 + 2996
>
> Thread 1:
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x000000021e86bb9c __workq_kernreturn + 8
> 1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000021e8f11c0 _pthread_wqthread + 540
>
> Thread 2:
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x000000021e85fea4 mach_msg_trap + 8
> 1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x000000021e85f37c mach_msg + 72
> 2 CoreFoundation 0x000000021ec65ad8 0x21ebb9000 + 707288
> 3 CoreFoundation 0x000000021ec60974 0x21ebb9000 + 686452
> 4 CoreFoundation 0x000000021ec600e0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
> 5 Foundation 0x000000021f656494 0x21f64e000 + 33940
> 6 Foundation 0x000000021f656340 0x21f64e000 + 33600
> 7 UIKitCore 0x000000024bf650c4 0x24b58c000 + 10326212
> 8 Foundation 0x000000021f78923c 0x21f64e000 + 1290812
> 9 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000021e8f025c 0x21e8e5000 + 45660
> 10 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000021e8f01bc _pthread_start + 48
>
> Thread 3:
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x000000021e85fea4 mach_msg_trap + 8
> 1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x000000021e85f37c mach_msg + 72
> 2 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x000000021e85b4ec thread_suspend + 84
> 3 JAnalytics 0x0000000100dc59e0 kscm_machexception_getAPI + 984
> 4 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000021e8f025c 0x21e8e5000 + 45660
> 5 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000021e8f01bc _pthread_start + 48
>
> Thread 4:
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x000000021e85fea4 mach_msg_trap + 8
> 1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x000000021e85f37c mach_msg + 72
> 2 JAnalytics 0x0000000100dc5a0c kscm_machexception_getAPI + 1028
> 3 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000021e8f025c 0x21e8e5000 + 45660
> 4 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000021e8f01bc _pthread_start + 48
>
> Thread 5:
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x000000021e85fea4 mach_msg_trap + 8
> 1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x000000021e85f37c mach_msg + 72
> 2 CoreFoundation 0x000000021ec65ad8 0x21ebb9000 + 707288
> 3 CoreFoundation 0x000000021ec60974 0x21ebb9000 + 686452
> 4 CoreFoundation 0x000000021ec600e0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
> 5 CFNetwork 0x000000021f28300c 0x21f281000 + 8204
> 6 Foundation 0x000000021f78923c 0x21f64e000 + 1290812
> 7 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000021e8f025c 0x21e8e5000 + 45660
> 8 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000021e8f01bc _pthread_start + 48
>
> Thread 6:
> 0 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000021e8f3ce8 0x21e8e5000 + 60648
>
> Thread 7:
> 0 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000021e8f3ce8 0x21e8e5000 + 60648
>
> Thread 8:
> 0 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000021e8f3ce8 0x21e8e5000 + 60648
>
> Thread 0 crashed with ARM-64 Thread State:
>
> Binary Images:
>
> Extra Information:
>
> Notable Addresses:
> {}
>
> Application Stats:
> {
> "active_time_since_last_crash": 0,
> "active_time_since_launch": 0,
> "application_active": false,
> "application_in_foreground": true,
> "background_time_since_last_crash": 0,
> "background_time_since_launch": 0,
> "launches_since_last_crash": 16,
> "sessions_since_last_crash": 16,
> "sessions_since_launch": 1
> }
> ```
>
> how to find where the exception has occurred and how to solve this

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash report

Comment: Are you trying to add new row or deleting a row? or when it crash

Comment: Isn't the error pretty obvious or do you have a lot of table views? _'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (51) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (50), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'_

Comment: this crash report is from a client, I don't know in which view controller this error occurred as I have lots of table view in my app...all I need is that, can we trace in which view controller this error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You've to check this line

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (51) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (50), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```